# ReplaceText with Regex in Apache Nifi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

Want to convert a set of different xml-files to Json. Nifi does not seem to understand the hierarky of the XMLs. Therefore we ended up stripping away the outer layers of the XML so we are left with just the inner segment  and its children, and then use ConvertRecord to concert this into Json.

So this is an example XML we read:

```
'''

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- =============================================================== -->
    <!--                                                                 -->
    <!--  DESCRIPTION:                                                   -->
    <!--                                                                 -->
    <!--   This is XML statistic file generated by the Statistics Export -->
    <!--   Interface feature. This file contains statistics from         -->
    <!--   statistical server for adequate time intervals.               -->
    <!--                                                                 -->
    <!-- =============================================================== -->
    <!DOCTYPE channel_statistics SYSTEM "../DTD/channel.dtd">
    <channel_statistics>\s*
      <header>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <creation_date_time>2020-02-16 01:25 UTC</creation_date_time>
        <zone_id>1</zone_id>
      </header>
      <data status="complete">
        <interval status="complete" start="2020-02-16 00:00 UTC" length="900">
          <channel channel_id="5" site_id="17" site_alias ="OF992BD01" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>900</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
          <channel channel_id="5" site_id="17" site_alias ="OF989BD01" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>900</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
          <channel channel_id="2" site_id="34" site_alias ="GF969BD31" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>0</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
        </interval>
      </data>
    </channel_statistics>
    '''
```

So by stripping it down to the interval-segment shown below, the ConvertRecord is able to read it.

```
    '''
        <interval status="complete" start="2020-02-16 00:00 UTC" length="900">
          <channel channel_id="5" site_id="17" site_alias ="OF082BS01" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>900</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
          <channel channel_id="5" site_id="17" site_alias ="OF082BS01" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>900</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
          <channel channel_id="2" site_id="34" site_alias ="OF041BS01" zone_id="1">
            <blocked_duration>0</blocked_duration>
            <control_channel_duration>0</control_channel_duration>
            <data_channel_allocation_count>0</data_channel_allocation_count>
            <data_channel_duration>0</data_channel_duration>
            <emergency_call_duration>0</emergency_call_duration>
            <emergency_calls>0</emergency_calls>
            <group_call_duration>0</group_call_duration>
            <group_calls>0</group_calls>
            <phone_call_duration>0</phone_call_duration>
            <phone_calls>0</phone_calls>
            <private_call_duration>0</private_call_duration>
            <private_calls>0</private_calls>
            <secondary_control_channel_duration>0</secondary_control_channel_duration>
            <interval_length>900</interval_length>
          </channel>
        </interval>

'''
```

Our setup is *ListFile->FetchFile->**ReplaceText**->ConvertRecord->...*

The ReplaceText processor is configured as following, but eigther does just pass the file unchanged to success or to failed queue with no error-message depending on what regex is used.

[ReplaceText processor config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl5y8.png)

Here are the different regex config tryed:

```
<interval(.*)</interval>
/\<interval(.*)interval\>/s
\<interval((.|\n|\r)*)interval\>
(?<=<data status="complete">)(.*?)(?=<\/data>)
(?s)(?<=<data status="complete">)(.*?)(?=<\/data>)
```

https://regexr.com/5330j

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Lauritz I was able to match with this regex:

```
<interval .*>([\s\S]*?)<\/interval>
```

Comment: In our ReplaceText_1.9.2-processor with the same config as shown above but with your regex, it only removes the line 
'<interval status="complete" start="2020-02-16 00:00 UTC" length="900">'
and leaves a blank linje with the rest of the XML as is.